# How to read different formats of XML file in OpenCv?

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

anybody know how to read Pascal VOC annotations in OpenCV? The format of annotations (xml files) is different from Opencv format. 
An example of annotation is shown below. As you see, it does not start with `<opencv_storage>` and values like `<filename>2007_000027.jpg</filename>` needs to be changed to `<filename>"2007_000027.jpg"</filename>` in order to avoid crash in reading. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
<annotation>
<folder>VOC2009</folder>
<filename>2007_000027.jpg</filename>
<source>
    <database>The VOC2007 Database</database>
    <annotation>PASCAL VOC2007</annotation>
    <image>flickr</image>
</source>
<size>
    <width>486</width>
    <height>500</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
    <name>person</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>174</xmin>
        <ymin>101</ymin>
        <xmax>349</xmax>
        <ymax>351</ymax>
    </bndbox>
    <part>
        <name>head</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>169</xmin>
            <ymin>104</ymin>
            <xmax>209</xmax>
            <ymax>146</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </part>
    <part>
        <name>hand</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>278</xmin>
            <ymin>210</ymin>
            <xmax>297</xmax>
            <ymax>233</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </part>
    <part>
        <name>foot</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>273</xmin>
            <ymin>333</ymin>
            <xmax>297</xmax>
            <ymax>354</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </part>
    <part>
        <name>foot</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>319</xmin>
            <ymin>307</ymin>
            <xmax>340</xmax>
            <ymax>326</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </part>
</object>
```

Comment: You can [use MSXML to read/write xml files](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.hk/2012/07/using-msxml-to-readwrite-xml-files.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the official [site](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/#bestpractice) of PASCAL VOC Challange, there are also some MATLAB tools for it.

> The PASCAL VOC project:
>
> Provides standardised image data sets for object class recognition
>   Provides a common set of tools for accessing the data sets and
>   annotations

With the help of PASCAL VOC Devkit, you can access and manipulate various types of annotation data in many ways, including reading them into special annotation Records, writing them as .txt and .xml files, using them for training and testing and so on.

Here are some avaliable devkits from different challanges;

- [2007](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2007/VOCdevkit_08-Jun-2007.tar)
- [2012](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2012/VOCdevkit_18-May-2011.tar)